# How can one make Clang optimize away useless array copies

Tags: c, arrays, llvm, clang

Consider the following C99 code (that uses the alloca extension.)

```
    void print_int_list(size_t size, int x[size]) {
            int y[size];
            memcpy(y, x, size * sizeof *x);

            for (size_t ii = 0; ii < size; ++ii)
                    printf("%i ", y[ii]);
            printf("\n");
    }

    void print_int_list_2(size_t size, int x[size]) {
            for (size_t ii = 0; ii < size; ++ii)
                    printf("%i ", x[ii]);
            printf("\n");
    }

    void print_int(int x) {
            int * restrict const y = alloca(sizeof x);
            memcpy(y, &x, sizeof x);
            printf("%d\n", *y);
    }

    void print_int_2(int x) {
            printf("%d\n", *x);
    }
```

In the code print_int is optimized to be exactly the same as print_int_2 on Clang version 3.0 but the function print_int_list is not optimized away to print_int_2. Instead the useless array copy is kept.

This sort of thing is not a problem for most people but it is for me. I intend to prototype a compiler by generating C code for use with Clang, (and later port it to LLVM directly), and I want to generate extremely stupid, simple, and obviously correct code, and let LLVM do the work of optimizing the code.

What I need to know is how one can make Clang optimize away useless array copies so that stupid code like print_int_list will get optimized into code like print_int_list_2.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the alloca implementation contains means to make it thread-safe. In that case the compiler can't just optimize it away, since it isn't allowed to optimize away thread synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: @Lundin I don't understand what you mean. If alloca couldn't be optimized then wouldn't it be impossible to optimize the print_int function too?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would go more carefully. There is a step inbetween the two cases that you have, arrays of fixed size. I think nowadays compilers can trace array components that are also indexed with a compile time constant.

Also don't forget that `memcpy` converts your *arrays* to pointers to the first element and then makes them `void*`. So it looses all information.

So I'd go

- try fixed sized arrays
- don't use `memcpy` but an assignment loop

and try to losen the constraints from there.

Comment: It should work for fixed size arrays but it doesn't, and the compiler actually converts an assignment loop into memcpy. @jens-gustedt

Comment: If one uses fixed size arrays, and manually unroll the assignment loop then the intermediate array disappears @jens-gustedt